# How do i play sound only once in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

I have created a game which has a mainform and I put a sound on the mainform for saying welcome to the player.
The problem is whenever I come back to the mainform the sound plays again.
How can I change it so it just play the first time when I enter the game?

Comment: Define a static bool property like `public static bool SoundPlayed {get;set;}` somewhere, like in the `Program` class, in the `Load` event handler of your main form, check if `Program.SoundPlayed` is false, then set it to true and play sound, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: See marble's answer in the linked duplicate